# Which Hero has the largest vision?

Tags: dota-2, dota

In Dota 1&2, Which heros have the largest vision at :

1. Night
2. Day
3. Both Combined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Night Stalker and Enchantress both have 1800 night vision. Here's a sortable [complete list](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Hero_Stats) of Hero Stats I put together a while ago that has a list of everyone's Night Vision in Dota2. In DotA, Meepo and Slark also both have 1800 night vision.
2. Night Stalker is an exception in that he is the only hero who does NOT see 1800 during the day, seeing only 1200.
3. Enchantress is the only hero in Dota2 right now that has full vision (1800) during both the day and night. In original DotA, Meepo and Slark share this combined 3600 vision.
4. Luna's passive skill Lunar Blessing provides her 1800 vision range during night.

Comment: Could be useful to add that Night Stalker with Aghanim's Sceptre get unobstructed vision at night, meaning that trees and terrain will not block his vision.

Comment: it could also be useful to add a list of heros that can augment their vision through their abilities and perhaps even a list of abilities that grant vision for a period of time

Comment: There are tons of abilities that grant vision, I don't think I could list half of them offhand. That could definitely be separate question.

Comment: maybe just the ones that provide a significant (and long lasting) advantage to sight then?  Such as beastmaster and venomancer.  You are right though, probably should be a different question.